# Stripe ephemeral key

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am following [this](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic#set-up-ephemeral-key) tutorial to add stripe to my android firebase app. The tutorial is asking me to "create a new user or account on your server, create a corresponding Customer object at the same time, even if you don’t collect payment information from your users when they sign up. This ensures that your application has a matching Customer for each user." How do I create this Customer Object?

Answer (score 0):

You can create customer in Stripe for your app users (after registration or before payment) using server-side codes as mentioned here [create customer](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic#set-up-ephemeral-key-server-side)